# Understanding ArrayLists and how they are used for a TUI

Tags: java, arraylist

Beforehand: This is a homework assignment so I need answers with explanations.
I am a first year student and my teacher is extremely vague while teaching so
I need some help understanding how to use the ArrayList in his instructions.

**I just need help understanding how this all works. I'm writing the code but I don't know how any of it works.

The Textual User Interface is supposed to be written in another class that I haven't done yet.**

My instructions were:

## GradeManager Class

Start by developing a class to describe a GradeManager.  Because this exercise is far more about writing an interactive application, we'll keep this class SIMPLE.  Our GradeManager will just keep track of an ArrayList of scores and define the following methods:

- A single constructor that accepts no parameters, but sets up the ArrayList so that it is 
  capable of holding some scores
- A method called addScore that will accept a score and add it to the ArrayList
- A method called getAverage that will return the average of all scores in the ArrayList

GradeTUI Class 
This class will keep track of a GradeManager object as an instance variable.  You will need to write a 
constructor that accepts the GradeManager object that it will be using.  
 
This class will also contain a method named run.  This method will give the user the ability to either (1) 
enter a score to be stored (in the GradeManager object) or (2) display the average of all scores entered 
so far.  Allow the user to continue this program by choosing one of these options until they are finished. 
 
Driver Class 
Once you are satisfied that these classes are defined and working properly, develop a driver class 
containing a main method that will create an instance of GradeManager, pass this object to the 
GradeTUI constructor, and then use the GradeTUI object to call run.

This is what I wrote:

```
public class GradeManager {
    private ArrayList<Integer> gradeList;


    public GradeManager() {
        ArrayList<Integer> gradeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        this.gradeList = gradeList;
    }


    public void addScore(int score) {
        this.gradeList.add(score);
    }


    public double getAverage(ArrayList<Integer> gradeList) {
        Integer aScore = 0;
        if (!gradeList.isEmpty()) {
            for (Integer grade : gradeList) {
                aScore += grade;
            }
            return aScore.doubleValue() / gradeList.size();
        }
        return aScore;

    }

}
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question. What problem are you having?

Comment: I'm sorry, but is there a question in there? Your code is a little verbose (e.g. you could bypass the shadowed local variable in the constructor with `this.gradeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();`) but it looks like it does as you were instructed.

Comment: I assume by "TUI" you mean "textual user interface"? Other than the phrase "this exercise is far more about writing an interactive application", I see nothing in the code or in your instructions about an interactive application at all. If this is all your teacher gave you, I think you've pretty much done all that you can do already.

Comment: If you've already wrote the code is because you understand, so what is your question exactly? Don't see need to explain, if you've solved by your own, then there's no question we can answer since you've already responded to yourself.

Comment: Sorry guys. I forgot to add what I was looking for help on. I don't understand what I'm doing. I write the code and I look at it and I can't put anything together. I don't know what I did or how it will work. Also, I don't know how I will use what I wrote here in the class that the user will interact with.

Comment: @user3241721 Then how did you write it? Scratch that... what part don't you understand?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I wrote it by taking it one part at a time and searching up how to do it. I don't understand how to use what I wrote here in another class that the user interacts with. Say the user inputs their grades, how will this class be accessed and used to get the average score?

Comment: The rest of the instructions were added to the OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: I think the getAverage Method should use the internal ArrayList instead of a parameter.
Otherwise you don't have any read access to that lists contents.

You can use your GradeManager in the following way:

```
GradeManager manager = new GradeManager();

while(condition) {
    int score = readScoreFromInput();
    manager.addScore(score);
}

double averageScore = manager.getAverage();
print(averageScore);
```

So you get the average of all the scores you have just input.
The concrete implementation of the loop (and the exit condition) is up to you - it could be a predefined number of iterations or a special input like `-1` for example.